# usage of “as many as”

Tags: phrase-usage, as

1. > One species, the giant armadillo, has **as many as** one hundred teeth, one of the largest numbers in a mammal. 
   > <sub>Source: [*The Amazing Armadillo: Geography of a Folk Critter*](http://books.google.com/books?id=VruNURXKNHwC&pg=PP12&lpg=PP12&dq=%22armadillos%20are%20members%20of%20the%20animal%20order%22&source=bl&ots=D2bPrk6nSz&sig=4f56Pz7YkrqAVPa0xri2JEt2VAQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=niVZVOz4A4ziaor3gKAK&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22armadillos%20are%20members%20of%20the%20animal%20order%22&f=false)</sub>
2. One species, the giant armadillo, has one hundred teeth, one of the largest numbers in a mammal.

I am wondering what the difference is between #1 and #2. I think you use “as many as” for emphasis, don't you?

Comment: It ackknowledges that 100 is the maximum - some giant armadillos have fewer than one hundred teeth. Wikipedia says '80-100'.

Comment: @StoneyB Any idea why in this construction 'as many as' isn't followed by an amount that's either equaled or surpassed? If I say *I'm as fast as X*, it normally means I am either as fast as X or *faster*. Why the blip for *as many as* do you reckon? Any theories?

Comment: It seems fairly synonymous with "up to". However, "as many as" couples nicely with "How many?" when the answer is somewhat unclear. "How many teeth does an armadillo have?" "Uhh, as many as 100." (Looked like a great build-up to a joke that first question...

Comment: Often the modality is made explicit: *can have as many as 100*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s a little confusing placed next to “has” (which might normally connote specificity), but this construction is used to indicate a bit of uncertainty and an upper limit.

The author is saying that if you find an armadillo somewhere, it will have between zero and one hundred teeth (probably closer to 100 if it hasn’t been boxing or eating lots of sweets). What’s impressive about this is that the number *could be* one hundred. I guess in a way there is a certain emphasis placed on that amount, but it doesn’t quite correspond to the emphasis that “*only* 100” would place on the number if the author wanted to say that it was relatively low.

To answer your question: There’s a bit of emphasis, yes, but this phrase is also used to simply state an upper limit to a given quantity. Note that the same words can also be used in a different kind of situation to express an *equal number,* as in “I have as many candy bars as she does.”